# Authorisation for webapp

Tags: google-docs

I have absolutely no knowledge of google docs but i need to investigate something:
Is it possible to authorize a user through google docs for a webapplication?

My app would not even have to handle the password, knowing if the user exists would be enough.

Why?: I'm building some tools for a client and they don't want to maintain users in each and every tool they have. For them now google docs is leading when it comes to maintaining users.
Obviously they don't want former employees using the tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides OpenID that you can use to link people to their Google Accounts.

Comment: It provides you are saying. That means it's optional? I wouldn't like to ask them to change to using OpenID if they're not.

Comment: If they are looked into a Google Account using OpenID is as simply as clicking on a clink and then on okay.